# Adding additional elements to the layout of different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

**Short Story :**

What will be my android app behavior when creating more elements in the Layouts assigned to certain devices and then programatically assigning an `onClickListener` to it?

**Long Story:**

I'm developing my Android app so that it will run in all types of android devices, according to that I created a certain Layouts for the **tablet devices** and another layouts for the **phone devices** using that [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html), now I want to add a `Button` in only the ***phone devices***, and it won't be exist in the ***tablet devices***, I'm asking here about the affection of this process on my app as I have to access that button programatically and add an `Listener` to it, I mean will my app crash when opening it from a **tablet**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a visual element in XML, you obtain a reference to it in the code using `findViewById()` method, e.g.

```
someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someButton);
```

If the button is available only for some layouts, it will return null when it's not available (calling this method is safe, it won't fail if the button is not in the layout). In such case, you will need to always check if the button is available (not null) before doing anything with it. Remember to check for null every time.

```
if (someButton != null) {
    // now you can use the button
}
```